# Did the medium range KTM tracking cameras for the Shuttle really have a "150 inch lens"?

Tags: launch, nasa, space-shuttle, photography

The Curious Droid YouTube video [How did NASA get those great film shots of Apollo and the Shuttle?](https://youtu.be/BlPfHV36G-g?t=566) found [here](https://curious-droid.com/393/nasa-filmed-apollo-shuttle-launches/) and linked-to in this [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27074/visibility-requirement-for-launch-when-can-it-be-ignored-or-mitigated-and?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment80337_27087) contains the following passage starting at `05:26`:

> This piece of footage here of the shuttle Discovery at T+40 seconds is shot from a medium distance camera about 3.8 kilometers from the launch pad **using a 150 inch lens with a 4,000 mm focal length** as the shuttle is accelerating through 20,000 feet. As discovery goes through a 145,000 feet at 123 seconds into flight, the boosters separate, which is captured here by another 150 inch, 4,000 mm focal length lens on a KTM. The weight of the lens alone on these was about 115 kilograms, and the tracking to keep the discovery in the frame was done by a human, and not an automated system. After three minutes the job of filming the ascent was transferred to the largest telescope on the site, the permanently mounted 24-inch aperture Recording Optical Tracking Instrument, or ROTI. With a focal length of up to 12,700 mm, ROTI had enough magnification to follow the launch for up to five minutes after liftoff. ROTI used both radar assisted tracking and a joystick for manual adjustment, which had such a fine sensitivity but it could register the heartbeat of the user if held too firmly.

High quality, imaging, achromatic lenses are never 150 inches (~3800 mm) in diameter. The [Yerkes Observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerkes_Observatory#Telescopes)'s 40 inch (1,000 mm) refractor is the largest diameter refracting telescope ever built, and that was about f/18.

Even if it were a reflecting 3.8 meter diameter primary, f/1.05 would be an impressive looking instrument.

**Question:** What are this optical system's actual specs, such as diameter of primary lens or mirror, focal length, and number of reflecting and/or refracting elements? It sounds amazing!

---

[image]

Comment: 4000 mm is just over 150", so the 150" refers to focal length, not diameter.

Comment: @Hobbes I thought about that kind of a mis-statement (f/1.05 seems a bit extreme) but I'm not sure.

Comment: @OrganicMarble [For want of a "c"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Want_of_a_Nail), the lens was organic. Thanks!

Comment: now all you need is an h...

Comment: @Hobbes (blush) I'll get there eventually. At least I spelled Yerkes right.

Comment: The Yerkes refractor was not the largest diameter ever build, the [Great Paris Exhibition Telescope of 1900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Paris_Exhibition_Telescope_of_1900) had a lens of 1.25 m (49 inch) diameter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The lens is a Brashear (now L3) [SR 150](http://www2.l3t.com/ios/pdf/SR_Range_Lens.pdf) lens.

[image: SR-150]

Focal length 150" - 3810 mm
Aperture 15.4" - 391 mm

This is a Cassegrain-type lens. The lenses are installed on an L3 [Kineto Tracking Mount](http://www2.l3t.com/brashear/products/ktm.htm).

A really good overview of all the photography going on during a Shuttle launch is [Ascent](https://sites.google.com/site/ascentcommemoratingshuttle/), an hour-long video that shows samples from each type of camera. Many of these cameras are high-speed, so you get fantastic slow-motion shots of the Shuttle taking off. The narration has a lot of detail on the cameras used, and all the stuff going on in the first minute after launch.

[This PDF](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/167722main_LaunchImagery06.pdf) has a map of the camera sites around the pad.

[image: short range cameras]

[image: medium range cameras]

Comment: Super-informative and well-sourced answer, thank you!

Comment: "Ascent" is indeed a remarkable film.

Comment: The Cassegrain telescope is not a refracting telescope, it is a reflecting telescope. It may be build without any lenses, only with curved mirrors.

Comment: you're right, but the term "lens" is used here as "the optical assembly in front of the film transport" as is common in photography. The manufacturer also calls it a lens.

Comment: So it is, in astronomer terms, a 15-inch f/10, approximately.