# What kinds of cameras were used to film Blue Origins first crewed flight launch?

Tags: camera, blue-origin

Obviously, the launch cameras were standard cameras (well high-tech expensive ones), and next ones used were drones, but... higher up, seemed like at first the cameras were following the rocket, too fast for drones.  And then the long shots, ground-based, but I'm guessing telescope kind?

Comment: This [Curious Droid video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/BlPfHV36G-g) might not be the answer but should at least be helpful

Comment: That covers a lot of history and details.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 that's an excellent video! I've used it [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27095/12102) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30680/12102).